# Высоконагруженный чат на php

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуйте!
Я столкнулся с выбором инструментария для чата с ориентировочным числом пользователей онлайн 1000.
У каждого пользователя чат должен обновляться автоматически (с интервалом или любым другим способом).
Проблема в том, какое выбрать хранилище для чата? `MySQL` может не выдержать тысячу одновременных запросов на выборку и плюс вставки. При этом все сообщения в хранилище вечно хранить не обязательно, т.е. в дальнейшем все может быть перенесено в базу `MySQL`.
Какое оптимальное хранилище можно выбрать для такой ситуации или какие есть альтернативы?
Либо какой можно взять проверенный готовый оупен соурс чат(с возможностью отправлять публичные и личные сообщения)?
При ответе прошу учесть нюансы сложности настройки сервера под данное решение.
Спасибо!

Comment: @white-imp, а как Вы представляете себе такой чат со стороны клиентов?

Ведь перед человеком постоянно (раз в секунду) будут изображаться новые сообщения. 

Видимо такой чат должен делиться на какие-то группы и клиент должен видеть изменения только в выбранных им группах.

Comment: На группы такой чат делиться не должен.
Как я себе это представляю - то пользователи чата между собой общаются не много. Они задают вопросы и отвечают на вопросы.
Чат будет в помощь онлайн трансляции видео или аудио.
Нагрузку MySQL может и выдержит в продакшне, но я полагаю, что у приложения должен быть достаточный запас на случаи пиковой загрузки.

Comment: Я ограничено только php?

Comment: На стороне сервера если писать самому - то да, php.

Comment: @white-imp просто я как думаю, раз кол-во человек более > 100, то это либо vps, либо выделенный со всеми вытекающими. По этому можно обойтись малой кровью - поставить node.js, и написать чатик в 100 строк, дабы с JavaScript'ом вы знакомы (я уверен в этом). Плюсы в том, что отпадут заморочки с memcached, mysql и другой нечестью.

Comment: Если писать будут мало, то insert'ов будет тоже мало, а select выполняется быстро, если уложитесь в 0.0001-0.001 за запрос, то проблем мне будет при обновлении раз в 5 сек.

Comment: @Dem, при высокой конкурентности, отработка PHP скрипта за 0.0001-0.001с, вообще возможна?(не считая случая с солидным сервером).

Или вы о db IO?

Comment: Не могу ответить по db io, но запрос 0.001 вполне реален на деволтной конфигурации слабого vps. При огромном количестве запросов конечно время будет выше, в данном вопросе конкуренции нет, особенно если реализовывать через ответ ниже.

Comment: @Dem не могу с вами согласиться, моя практика говорит совсем о другом, ну да ладно

Comment: Поделитесь пожалуйста, что говорит Ваша практика? Мне интересно.

Comment: @Dem, как минимум о том, что добиться стабильного выполнения PHP скрипта за 0.0001-0.001с не представляеться возможным, хотя, наверное, я просто не умею готовить.

Comment: Вот например, debug одного моего сайта - vps, стандартная конфигурация mysql, cpu 1000, озу 700, в таблице 60к записей

`0.0002: SELECT v.id, v.`code`, v.`name`, v.`experience`, v.`date`, v.`price_from`, ..., v.parsed_date FROM kv_vacancy AS v LEFT JOIN kv_company AS co ON co.id = v.company_id LEFT JOIN kv_category AS ca ON ca.id = v.category_id WHERE v.id = 50722`

`0.0019: SELECT id, `name`, `price_from`, `price_to`, `valute` FROM kv_vacancy WHERE (`code` LIKE '%voditel%' OR `code` LIKE '%kurer%') AND id >= 50561 LIMIT 20`

Comment: @Dem, не, ну без IO, без http и при нулевой конкурентности, не исключаю.

Comment: @Dem, IMHO Вы не учитываете время запуска самого PHP скрипта.

Вот такая "пустышка"

      while (i) {
        if (!fork())
          execl("./a.out", "a.out", "-1", NULL);
        i--;
        wait(0);
      }

и такой результат

    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/dispro/alfa$ time ./a.out 1000
    1000 loops
    Fini
    real 0m4.542s
    user 0m0.212s
    sys  0m1.224s
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/dispro/alfa$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
    model name : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5400  @ 2.70GHz
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/dispro/alfa$ 

Думаю, что у Вас время выполнения запроса *внутри* mysql.

Comment: @Dem, должен добавить, что предыдущий вариант на виртуалке. На реальном сервере fork/exec ведут себя значительно лучше

    [avp@nas ~]$ time ./a.out 1000
    1000 loops
    Fini
    real 0m0.362s
    user 0m0.067s
    sys  0m0.336s
    [avp@nas ~]$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
    model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz

Т.е. разница в скорости запуска может различаться на порядок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1000 пользователей не будут давать 1000 запросов в секунду.
Как вариант, актуальный список сообщений хранить в memcache, т.е. все запросы будут сводиться к кэшу, а каждые сколько-то минут синхронизировать с тем же мускулем.

Если без кэша, то можно nosql попробовать, MongoDB, запросы быстрее, но требовательнее к ресурсам системы.

Comment: 1000 запросов имел ввиду, что у каждого юзера на стороне клиента будет авторефреш.
Каким образом тогда в случае memcache и mysql будет происходить обновление чата на стороне юзера?

Comment: Рефреш каждую секунду? Хотите канал забить? А если через 3g заходить?

Сторона юзера отправляет сообщение и запрашивает сообщения, тут ничего не меняется.

Memcache - это серверное решение.

Comment: Смотрите, юзер1 пишет сообщение, оно добавляется в memcache, от юзера2 пришел запрос на рефреш, сообщения запрашиваются из memcache и уходят юзеру2. Ни одного запроса в базу пока небыло. Доспустим через 5 мин по крону запускается синхронизация и переносит сообщения из кэша в базу, хотя непонятно зачем она вообще тут нужна.

Comment: Чат будет начинаться по расписанию и длиться час-два. Синхронизация нужна для хранения истории.
Про 3G можно забыть, т.к. по требованиям должен быть скоростной интернет на стороне пользователя.
Dem, уточните, пожалуйста, как часто будут приходить от юзера2 запросы на рефреш? Интервалом или как?

Comment: Это уже Вам решать, как захотите так и будет.

Comment: Если все уперлось в PHP, то, как хранилище и как кэш, предлагаю использовать redis, помоему это самое очевидное решение. Memcache убог в плане типов данных и ограниченного применения, а mysql намного медленее их обоих, да и, банально, не нужен.

btw крайне не рекомендую использовать xhr polling.

Answer (score 3):

1000 запросов - это не так много. Они встанут в очередь и выполнятся, учитывая то, что время выполнения очень небольшое(вы же говорите, что сообщения не надо хранить вечно!)
insert и select по простым критериям(в вашем случае - select по дате) происходят очень быстро, особенно, если правильно расставить индексы.

Наконец, 1000 пользователей в ОДНОЙ комнате - это очень утомительно: чат будет убегать быстрее, чем вы будете успевать прочитывать. Комнаты можно раскидать по таблицам.

Еще вариант, который, правда, пока поддерживается очень слабо - сокеты. Костыль состоит в том, что соединение, как бы, не закрывается вообще: страница в вечном ожидании ответа сервера. В таком случае, ответ уходит всем синхронно, а значит, база дергается в 1000 раз меньше на выборку.